# Counterexample that for pointwise limit $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x_n) = f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis

We need to let $f_n$ be a row of continues functions on the interval [0,1] that converge pointwise . The condition for the equality: for each a $\in$ [0,1] and each row $x_n$ in [0,1] that converges to a.

I was thinking about looking for a row of functions which converges to a discontinues function such that the f(a) would not exist, but i can not find an example of this.

Another example i had in mind was the function: f= 2nx if 0<= x< 1\2n
f = 2-2nx if 1\2n<=x<1\n and f= 0 when 1\n <= x <= 1
and the row $x_n$=1\n. But I do not know if the limit of the functions equals 0 when n $\to \infty$.

Can anybody help me to find this counter example?

Comment: In your last example, use $x_n=1/(2n)$. Then $f_n(x_n)=1$ for all $n$, but the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ is the zero function (since the base of the "spikes"  get smaller and smaller).